# Some email not received if sent by phpmailer, but ok if sent by normal email client software

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have problems with some people that doesn't receive email sent by a script in PHP using phpmailer.

I tell her to check inside spam folder. They tell me: No email received.

Then if I try to send the same email, but using a normal client like outlook or thunderbird, using same text, same subject and same attachment, the email arrive correctly to destination.

Email sent by phpmailer was sent using a gmail account.

If I try to check email sent from gmail.com (web) I see it was correctly sent without returned fail messages.

Destination email is not a gmail address.

Any idea to check what is the problem?

My simple script is:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = (boolean)$impostazioni['SMTPAuthPHPMailer'];
$mail->SMTPSecure = $impostazioni['SMTPSecurePHPMailer'];
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
          'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
          )
        );

    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = (boolean)$impostazioni['SMTPAutoTLSPHPMailer'];
    $mail->Host = gethostbyname($impostazioni['hostPHPMailer']);// Specify main SMTP servers
    $mail->Username = $impostazioni['usernamePHPMailer'];       // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = $impostazioni['passwordPHPMailer'];       // SMTP password
    $mail->Port = $impostazioni['portPHPMailer'];               // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->Timeout = 60;

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($emailMittente, $nomeMittente);


    $mail->addAddress($info_destinatario['Email']); 

    $mail->addReplyTo($opzioni['ReplyTo']);

    $mail->AddCustomHeader( "X-Confirm-Reading-To: $emailMittente" );
    $mail->AddCustomHeader( "Disposition-Notification-To: $emailMittente" );

    $mail->AddCustomHeader( "Return-Receipt-To: $emailMittente" );



    $track = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $tracker = "<img border='0' src='" . ROOTURL . "tracker/index.php?track=$track' alt='' />";



    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);    // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
    $mail->Subject = $oggetto;
    $mail->Body    = $template;
    $mail->AltBody = $plaintext;

    if( $mail->Send() ) {
        $result['Error'] = false;
        $result['ErrorDetail'] = "";
        $result['Message'] = "Messaggio inviato";
        $result['Tracker'] = $track;
        $result['MessageID'] = $mail->GetLastMessageID();
    } else {
        $result['Error'] = true;
        $result['ErrorDetail'] = $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $result['Message'] = $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $result['Tracker'] = "";
        $result['MessageID'] = "";
    }

    return $result;
```

I tried send email to: mail-tester.com and only problem I get was here:

```
3 blacklist:

Presente in BACKSCATTERER ( -0.5 )
Presente in SORBS (last 48 hours) ( -0.5 )
Presente in SORBS (last 28 days) ( -0.5 )
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you setting the "From" field in PHPMailer to a different address than the Gmail account you're sending from? That can show up as an attempt at spoofing or spam, and cause some email servers to reject the message. From your code, it's unclear where the `$emailMittente` value comes from - is it set by the user, or by your application? It should be the same every time, and it should match the email address of the account you're using to log onto the SMTP server. You should certainly never allow the user to set this value.

Comment: Also, even apart from the From field, I suspect maybe your manually sent emails are not exactly the same in other ways - do those manually sent emails contain all the custom headers you've added using your code, for example?

Comment: hi @ADyson, yes $emailMittente is the same as $impostazioni['usernamePHPMailer'] ... my custom header can be set in the client using "Check delivery  / check confirmation reading" option. I've update my post, I see the IP where phpmailer is executed was blacklisted on 3 sites...maybe the problem here?

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug = 2` and you can watch the message being delivered, or not.

Comment: Yes, blacklisting would potentially be an issue. Thing is you need to work out _why_ you got blacklisted to begin with.